# Couldn't find the examples.pri file

Tags: qt

I am using Qt Creator 4.0.3
Based on Qt 5.7.0 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit)

and I tried to run this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdatavisualization-surface-example.html

but got an error: :-1: error: Couldn't find the examples.pri file!
and I couldn't find in web solution of this problem..

It is like I have no such examples? How to include them painless into my system? 
Maybe there is an easy way to fix it.

Comment: It's OK to remove the lines that are related to `examples.pri`.

Comment: I tried, but then it is going to appear more errors in the code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the file from the Qt local installation path, ie from:

```
/opt/Qt5.7.0/Examples/Qt-5.7/datavisualization/examples.pri
```

Usually the file includes project configuration related information:

```
requires(qtHaveModule(multimedia))

!include( ../examples.pri ) {
    error( "Couldn't find the examples.pri file!" )
}

QT += 3dcore 3dquick qml quick multimedia

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    touchsettings.cpp

HEADERS += \
    touchsettings.h

OTHER_FILES += \
    *.qml

RESOURCES += \
    audio-visualizer-qml.qrc
```

Comment: Where is this file? I can't find it under `/opt`