# QT: Where to find examples.pri file

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5, qmake

I am following [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html) example to make solid objects in `QT`. The example requires a `.pri` file called `examples.pri` which I am unable to locate.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747834/couldnt-find-the-examples-pri-file) question asks the same thing but the given answer says to search in the file in `/opt/Qt...` which does not match my installation path. In my installation path (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5`), I do not have a `.pri` file.

Commenting out the required line does not create any errors other than those in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252186/qt-qmake-not-recognising-3dcore-3drender) question, and I think those errors may be resolved by getting the correct `.pri` file.

So,from where can I get the required `.pri` file, or alternatively, how to resolve the errors occurring in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252186/qt-qmake-not-recognising-3dcore-3drender) question.

Comment: It is in `../examples.pri` relative to the directory where your `basicshapes-cpp.pro` is in. If it is not there, it is missing in your system package.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += 3dextras

target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/qt3d/$$TARGET
INSTALLS += target
```

Copy and paste it in an *example.pri* file located one dir above the *basicshapes-cpp.pro* file.

That file is not so important to build and run the example, though. I'm quite sure if you comment out these lines in *basicshapes-cpp.pro* it would work anyway, even without the `pri` file:

```
#!include( ../examples.pri ) {
#    error( "Couldn't find the examples.pri file!" )
#}
```

You can add `TEMPLATE = app`, just for the sake of correctness, but you don't need the install settings, until you don't run a `make install`. The `3dextras` module is redundant (added in the .pro, already).

Notice that what I suggested here is just a workaround, which could not work at all (i.e. you downloaded the project files from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html) but your Qt version is lesser than 5.7 and has no `3dextras` module at all).

The proper way to build and run the example, is using Qt Creator: go to the  welcome page, select *Examples*, search *Basic Shapes* and, if it is found, click on it and you're done.

Comment: It shows the same error: `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: 3dextras`

Comment: @marpangal please see if the update to my answer is of any help.

Comment: I checked my QT version, it is `5.9.1`. Also I am unable to find `Basic Shapes` example in my QT creator IDE.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian, it's included in the `qt3d5-examples` package:

```
$ dlocate examples\\.pri
qt3d5-examples:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/examples/qt3d/examples.pri
```